# win phone 7 and SoundEffect problem

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

Hi I use this way to play soundeffect

```
SoundEffect _effect; 
using (var stream  = TitleContainer.OpenStream(path))
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        _effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
    } 
}

...

void play()
{
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    _effect.Play();
}
```

I think that is right but something strange happens when play long sound (30 sec) and in the same time play other sound...
the strange phenomenon is that seems that stream is dirty I hear the end of other sound just played, I have not tried on the phone but only on emulator...

I made this code on windows 7 32-bit with windows phone toolkit visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

1) if you're not an XNA game, but you're using xna stuff for sound, you're supposed to call `FrameworkDispatcher.Update` regularly, not just once. (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/ac432a85-3109-445c-ac85-46e3a716e9ce)

2) are your sounds set as "Resource" or as "Content" in your project?  there is some wierdness where things will seem to work as resource, but they really should be set to content.

Comment: thanks for answer, I call every 50 msec FrameworkDispatcher, I put sound into subdirectory inside project is not embeded into resource. it seems a problem in stream, when I play one sound and is near to end and than play soon an other the last one play the end of previuos sound for two times then play the sound assigned, and if sound is really short it play last sound then the new sound

Comment: if the sound is in a "subdirectory inside project", then it is "in your project".  is it set to be a content or a resource in the project?

Comment: Content for sure, also because I have 100 file sounds

Comment: problem solved on real device this bug don't appear so is a bug of my emulator or something like that :)